# Compress mtdblock with 'tar' before sending it via TFTP

Tags: linux, tar, embedded, busybox, tftp

what is proper command compress mtdblock with 'tar' before sending it via TFTP?

```
tftp -l /dev/mtdblock3 -p 192.168.100.40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar` is not a compression tool, just use `gzip` to compress a single file.

You can pipe `gzip -c` to `tftp -l /dev/stdin` on the busybox shell.  For example:

```
gzip -c /dev/mtdblock3 | tftp -l /dev/stdin -r mtdblock3.gz -p 192.168.100.40
```

If there's no `/dev/stdin`, try with `/proc/self/fd/0` instead.

Comment: In my case BusyBox v1.4.2 implementation have no `gzip` function defined, very limited.

Comment: Run `busybox --help` to get list of available applets.  Possible alternatives for `gzip` would be `bzip2`, `lzma`, `lzop`, or `xz`.  Otherwise you'll need an external command for compression.

Comment: Unfortunately, these alternatives is not available too.